# AWS Config rules evaluations count

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-config

AWS Newbie here.

Guys, can you help on how to can get/view the current count of AWS Config rules evaluations?

https://aws.amazon.com/config/pricing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [link](https://aws.amazon.com/config/pricing/) provided:

> A rule evaluation is recorded every time a resource is evaluated for compliance against an AWS Config rule.

When you evaluate your rules using [periodic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/evaluate-config-rules.html#aws-config-rules-trigger-types) triggers, calculations of the number of evaluations is straightforward, e.g. once every 24 hours.

However, since Config does not have any CloudWatch Metrics, monitoring the triggers based on [Configuration changes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/evaluate-config-rules.html#aws-config-rules-trigger-types) is getting tricky.  One way to overcome this in an **automated way**, would be to setup [SNS notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/monitor-resource-changes.html) for `Config`. The SNS could trigger a lambda each time a rule is being evaulated (i.e. a resource is being created/deleted or changed) and have the lambda produce a **custom metric** for that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check that option. Hopefully AWS will add an current count for Config resources changes for us to know the pricing better rather than doing an estimation.

Comment: @markreyes1110 No problem. Probably in cost explorer you should find some details, but its not real time like CW metrics would be.